# Django dynamic Form using json data

Tags: python, json, django

I have seen many examples of dynamic forms, but it seems I could not find my answer, So please help me on the requirement below:

I have a json file including some data as below:

```
    {
    "cat1": {
        "product1": {
            "item1": "check box p1i1",
            "item2": "check box p1i2",
            "item3": "check box p1i3"
        },
        "product2": {
            "item1": "check box p2i1",
            "item2": "check box p2i2",
            "item3": "check box p2i3"
        }
    },
    "cat2": {
        "product1": {
            "item1": "check box p1i1",
            "item2": "check box p1i2",
            "item3": "check box p1i3"
        },
        "product2": {
            "item1": "check box p2i1",
            "item2": "check box p2i2",
            "item3": "check box p2i3"
        }
    }
}
```

I have presented the data based on the category then item, so user will select category first then select items that he wants, and based on that I will filter the json file based on the selection, and then present it as form in relevant template:

The question is since the created form is not Django Form so how I can get the posted data in the view, (there will be an input box and several check box (based on user selection)

#### views.py

```
def select_cat1(request, item):
    if request.method=='POST':
        ?(how to get posted data here?)

    else:
     data = open(json_file).read()
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        product_list = {}
        for key in json_data.get('cat1'):
            product_list[key] = json_data['cat1'][key][item]
        return render(request, 'cat1.html', {'item': item, 'product_list': product_list })

def select_cat2(request, item):
  if request.method=='POST':
        ?(how to get posted data here?)

    else:
     data = open(json_file).read()
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        product_list = {}
        for key in json_data.get('cat2'):
            product_list[key] = json_data['cat2'][key][item]
        return render(request, 'cat2.html', {'item': item, 'product_list': product_list })
```

#### cat1.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label>enter your phone:</label>  
    <input type="text" id="mobile_number">

    {% for key, value in product_list.items %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ key }}"> {{ value }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting multiple products with same items. Because of that the input has same names (item1, item2, item3) and you can not separate the products. You have to include the product id with item id in your input's name attribute.

The other "problem" is that you have separated the views to handle categories. Multiple views are not needed if you pass category as an parameter and submit back from the view.

**views.py**

```
def select_cat(request, item, category):
    data = open(json_file).read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    product_list = json_data.get(category)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # loop through json product_list and check try to get items from request.POST
        for (product_key, product) in product_list.items():

            # loop through submited values from request.POST
            for (item_key, item) product.items():
               submited_item =  request.POST['%s-%s' % (product_key, item_key)]



    else:
        return render(request, 'category.html', {
           'item': item, 
           'product_list': product_list,
           'category': category
        })
```

**category.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="POST" action="url with category here">{% csrf_token %}
        <label>enter your phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="mobile_number" />

        {% for product_key, product in product_list %}
            {% for item_key, item in product %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ product_key }}-{{ item_key }}" value="{{ product_key }}-{{ item_key }}" />{{ item_value }}<br />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and recommendations, but still this is not my answer, The question is I have already parsed the json file and rendered in the template AS FORM, so this form is not django form, and once user clicked on submit, then I need to have the input box (value) and the items that user checked them via checkbox, so :

if request.method == 'POST':
(Here I need the items that has been checked as checkbox and also I need the input box value)

Comment: You will get submitted items inside if request.method == 'POST' by using request.POST['%s-%s' % (product_key, item_key)]